# Angular HTML: ng-content in ngSwitch

Tags: html, css, angular

The ng-content doesn't work in Angular ngSwitch case. ng-content for the code below only work in default case but not in other case.

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="variant">
    <button *ngSwitchCase="variantType.SUCCESS">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </button>
    <button *ngSwitchCase="variantType.WARNING">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </button>
    <button *ngSwitchCase="variantType.ERROR">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </button>
    <button *ngSwitchDefault>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </button>
</ng-container>
```

But if code below works again. I have no idea how to make the ng-content work in switchCase. Is there any way to allow multiple ng-content so that the code below will works.

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="variant">
    <button *ngSwitchCase="variantType.SUCCESS">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </button>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question to your answer can be found here: https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#conditional-content-projection

The actual problem is described pretty good there:

> Using an  element in these cases is not recommended, because when the consumer of a component supplies the content, that content is always initialized, even if the component does not define an  element or if that  element is inside of an ngIf statement.
> With an  element, you can have your component explicitly render content based on any condition you want, as many times as you want. Angular will not initialize the content of an  element until that element is explicitly rendered.

The solution is also described pretty good:

> If your component needs to conditionally render content, or render content multiple times, you should configure that component to accept an  element that contains the content you want to conditionally render.

This means you should use the following code to achieve what you are trying to:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="variant">
  <button *ngSwitchCase="variantType.SUCCESS">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container>
  </button>
  <button *ngSwitchCase="variantType.WARNING">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container>
  </button>
  <button *ngSwitchCase="variantType.ERROR">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container>
  </button>
  <button *ngSwitchDefault>
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container>
  </button>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Alright thanks for the information and links provided. Thank you!